# Terminating while thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I can't close my thread. Am I forgetting to do something? The thread seems like it's saving the value I'm using for close, and then never checks if it has changed. Here is some example code that has an identical effect:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class test {
private:
    bool user_wants_thread = true;
    bool time_to_close = false;

public:
    bool set_timetoclose(bool in) {
        time_to_close = in;
        if (time_to_close == in) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void function() {
        while (user_wants_thread) {
            // CODE
            std::cout << time_to_close;
            Sleep(100);
            if (time_to_close) {
                goto close;
            }
        }
    close:
        Sleep(1);
    }
};

int main() {
    test t;

    std::thread thread_func(&test::function, t);
    Sleep(1000);

    bool success;
    do {
        success = t.set_timetoclose(true);
    } while (!success);

    thread_func.join();
    std::cout << "Closed";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Can't be certain it makes sense  in a full code implementation, but in this example, `break;` in place of the `goto close;` would raise fewer eyebrows.

Comment: Well, my program is actually inside multiple threads, and the main function is just for some initial set up. Closing the thread when not expecting it == you're not running the program. (This has proper indenting, at least as proper as visual studio sets)

Comment: Break has the same effect, sure, but it still fails.

Comment: You can save yourself some messiness in `set_timetoclose` by turning your flags into `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: Mostly. the `goto` and the `break` have the same effect in the code, but significantly fewer people sharpening stakes, honing pitchforks and lighting torches at in a code review.

Comment: This whole thing is just one huge pile of undefined behavior, due to a complete lack of sequencing. Scrap it, and rewrite it from scratch, but only after you reread all the chapters in your C++ book that discuss, in detail, mutexes, condition variables, and sequencing.

Comment: This is just example code. I will look into mutexes, condition variables, and sequencing, though.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can correct me if I'm wrong, but for example, I believe it's completely legal for the compiler to hoist the `while (user_wants_thread) {` bit out of the loop, and only load the value of `user_wants_thread` once, since nothing else is allowed to change it, because it's not synchronized in any way.

Comment: Correct, if the compiler is aware that `Sleep()`, and the formatted I/O operation have no side effects, which is entirely plausible.

Comment: `break` only breaks the closest loop. Outer loops are unaffected. It's the "I need to break many loops" case where a `goto` might be defensible. Abstracting with another function and a return may be preferable, though.

Comment: right, so I might just use a return; instead of a break, but the issue is it's reading time_to_close as 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed some unused parts and changed the actual condition to be an `atomic<bool>` and it seems to work as shown on this link:

http://rextester.com/TWHK12491

I'm not claiming this is absolutely correct, however, but it shows how using the atomic causes synchronization across reads/writes to the value which could result in a data race.

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
class test {

public:
    std::atomic<bool> time_to_close = false;

    test()=default;
    void function() {
        while (!time_to_close) {
            std::cout << "Running..." << std::endl;
            Sleep(100);
        }
        std::cout << "closing" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    test t;
    std::thread thread_func([&t](){t.function();});
    Sleep(500);

    t.time_to_close = true;
    std::cout << "Joining on thread" << std::endl;
    thread_func.join();
    std::cout << "Closed";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does an atomic value need to be public?

Comment: @vidsac no.  I was just trying to remove as much unnecessary complexity as possible.  Hiding the variable and having an accessor isn't relevant to the issue you had and it made the code more complex for the purpose of your question and my answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks. will give it a go and report back here ;)

Comment: @vidsac one issue you may run into, however, is that the object containing an atomic<bool> can not be copied using the default copy constructor.   Copying seems to be required for caling std::thread the way you were doing it - you'll notice I changed it to a lambda that captures t by reference, instead of by value

Comment: ya i ran into that problem, but luckily your suggestion fixed it :) thanks a ton for the help!